# What is this white flower found on a lake shore in Maine?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]White flower found on a lake shore in Maine.

Comment: What time of year was it when you took that picture? Was it in the mountains? How high above see level? - feel free to edit your initial question.

Comment: The picture was taken on September 4th, 2016 and the lake is in the mountains about 122 feet above sea level.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption the foliage in the picture is part of the flowers (its hard to tell from the pic) it appears to be Chelone glabra, common name turtlehead, a plant which occurs in the wild in wet or damp ground, often near water. It's a perennial plant which is in flower between July and October.

http://www.northcreeknurseries.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/mobile.plant/ID/153

Comment: A lovely plant for a damp or wet location.  A cultivar has purplish flowers.

Comment: The long slender leaves are part of the flowers plant. From the picture you linked it looks like you found it. Surprised it is a perennial, this is the first time we have see those flowers on our property and there was at least 4 other like plants nearby.

Comment: Well its perennial in Missouri and the UK - might have germinated by bird dropped seed or something, but should regrow next year unless you're in the Arctic!